# Is there any option to read the status of services in any way through protractor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, service, protractor

When we run any of web application, application calls the webservices internally, by any way can we get to know the status of the http service call in protractor?
I know about node-fetch package which works as typical service call by sending request and getting the response. But what i am looking for is, when application is running can we get the status of service , if it has returned success 200 or failure 400 ,etc. Any such option we have in protractor?

Answer (score 0):

In my test environment, I had similar problems. I needed to access application internal functionality, for checking if a certain request was finished for example.

The final solution was to expose functionality through `window` object. Tests can access `window` using `browser.executeScript()`.

### Tutorial

#### within web-application:

1. Create a `class` with all functionality you want to use in `protractor` tests. In this particular case, we wanna pass a string to web-application, log it, and pass it back to tests.

```js
export class E2EDriver {

    public give_id_back = async (id: string): Promise<string> => {
        // Application internal logic here. We can access anything since we are
        // within the real application.
        console.log("Driver is running something within web-application!, id:",id)
        return id
    }
}
```

2. inject this class into `window` obejct.

```js
const global = window as any
global.e2e_driver = new E2EDriver()
```

#### within protractor tests:

Now, the window object holds the newly added `E2EDriver` class. It's time to get access
to the driver in our tests:

1. Create the bridge via `browser.executeScript()`

```
// This is a string of code which is passed to browser.executeAsyncScript()
const javascript_run_driver_fn = `

   // remove function name from args
   var args = [...arguments].splice(1);

   // remove callback provided by protractor from args
   var cb = args.splice(args.length-1, 1)[0];

   // invoke requested function with given args and respond using cb()
   e2e_driver[arguments[0]](...args).then(cb).catch(cb);
`;

// the real bridge..
const run_in_driver = async <T = void>(_browser: ProtractorBrowser, key: string, ...args: any[]): Promise<T> => {
   return await _browser.executeAsyncScript<T>(javascript_run_driver_fn, key, ...(args || []))
}

let driver: E2EDriver = null

// For gettign access to the driver in protractor tests.
export class E2eDriverApi {

   public static driver = async (_browser: ProtractorBrowser): Promise<E2eDriver> => {
       if(driver) {
           return driver
       }

       // get existing e2e-driver functions
       const real_driver = await _browser.executeScript<E2eDriver>("return e2e_driver;")
       const test_driver = { }

       // expose functions from real_driver using browser.executeScript() API
       // this creates the bridge..
       Object.keys(real_driver).forEach(k => {
           test_driver[k] = (...args: any[]) => run_in_driver(_browser, k, ...args)
       })

       driver = test_driver as E2eDriver
       return driver

   }
}
```

This code, takes the `e2e_driver` object from `window` and wraps it up in a new object. In this new object, all functions will be executed using `browser.executeAsyncScript()` and it's results will be returned.

Unfortunately, the `E2EDriver`is limited to use functions returning a `Promise`, since we use this `async` api.

2. Use driver in some test:

```js
import {  E2eDriverApi } from "./path/to/file"
import { browser } from "protractor"

describe("Given, web application", () => {

    describe("When started", () => {

        it("should e2e-driver be available", async () => {
            const driver = await E2eDriverApi.driver(browser)
            const id = await driver.give_id_back("I should be written to console")
            expect(id).toEqual("I should be written to console")
        })

    })
})
```

I hope this helps.
Ask if anything is unclear.

cheers.!